# Why is my modal window not closing after a click?

Tags: javascript, html, css, modal-dialog

I have  two elements on my HTML. In each of the labels there is a question mark icon wrapped in. A click on a question mark fires a modal window. This is my html code looks like

```
<form>
<div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label col-md-4 col-lg-3 required" for="offer_title" id="ThemaLbl">
                <div class="inline-help form-label"><i onClick="myFunction('themaModal')" class="fa fa-question-circle-o" id="ThemaHilfe"></i></div>Thema</label>
            <div class="col-md-8 col-lg-9">
                <textarea class="longInput" cols="42" rows="1" id="ThemaTextfield"></textarea>
            </div>
</div>

<!-- The Modal -->
        <div id="themaModal" class="modal">

            <!-- Modal content -->
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modalheader">
                    <h2><p><b id="hilfeTitel">Wie kann ich eine neue Anzeige erstellen?</b></p></h2>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <p style="display: block;"><font size="6" id="hilfeText"><b id="hilfeText">Sie wollen eine neue Anzeige anlegen?</b> Dann tragen Sie die zugehörigen Informationen ein und speichern
        das Ergebnis am Ende ab.</font></p>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <div class="panel panel-default" id="feedback-form">
                        <div class="panel-heading">
                            <h4 class="panel-title" id="hilfeQuestion">
        <i class="fa fa-question-circle"></i> Waren die Informationen für Sie hilfreich? </h4>
                        </div>
                        <div class="panel-body">
                            <form class="feedback" id="new_feedback" role="form" action="/feedbacks" method="post" accept-charset="UTF-8" data-remote="true">
                                <input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="✓">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <textarea name="feedback[comment]" class="form-control" id="feedback_comment" placeholder="Sie können uns hier Ihre Anmerkungen mitteilen."></textarea>
                                </div>
                                <input name="feedback[context]" id="feedback_context" type="hidden" value="/offers/new">
                                <input name="feedback[help_key]" id="feedback_help_key" type="hidden" value="help.offers.new">
                            </form>
                            <div class="hidden response">
                                Vielen Dank für Ihr Feedback!
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="sa-button-container">
                        <button tabindex="2" class="cancel" style="display: none; box-shadow: none;">Cancel</button>
                        <div class="sa-confirm-button-container">
                            <button id="commentOK" tabindex="1" class="confirm" style="display: inline-block; box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px rgba(140,212,245,0.8), inset 0px 0px 0px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.05);">OK</button>
                            <div class="la-ball-fall">
                                <div></div>
                                <div></div>
                                <div></div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

<div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label col-md-4 col-lg-3" for="offer_content" id="InhaltLbl">
                <div class="inline-help form-label" ><i onClick="myFunction('inhaltModal')" class="fa fa-question-circle-o" id="InhaltHilfe"></i></div>Inhalt</label>
            <div class="col-md-8 col-lg-9">
                <textarea class="longInput" cols="42" rows="4" id="InhaltTextfield"></textarea>
            </div>
        </div>

        <!-- The Modal -->
        <div id="inhaltModal" class="modal">

            <!-- Modal content -->
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modalheader">
                    <h2><p><b id="hilfeTitel">Wie kann ich eine neue Anzeige erstellen?</b></p></h2>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <p style="display: block;"><font size="6" id="hilfeText"><b id="hilfeText">Sie wollen eine neue Anzeige anlegen?</b> Dann tragen Sie die zugehörigen Informationen ein und speichern
        das Ergebnis am Ende ab.</font></p>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <div class="panel panel-default" id="feedback-form">
                        <div class="panel-heading">
                            <h4 class="panel-title" id="hilfeQuestion">
        <i class="fa fa-question-circle"></i> Waren die Informationen für Sie hilfreich? </h4>
                        </div>
                        <div class="panel-body">
                            <form class="feedback" id="new_feedback" role="form" action="/feedbacks" method="post" accept-charset="UTF-8" data-remote="true">
                                <input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="✓">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <textarea name="feedback[comment]" class="form-control" id="feedback_comment" placeholder="Sie können uns hier Ihre Anmerkungen mitteilen."></textarea>
                                </div>
                                <input name="feedback[context]" id="feedback_context" type="hidden" value="/offers/new">
                                <input name="feedback[help_key]" id="feedback_help_key" type="hidden" value="help.offers.new">
                            </form>
                            <div class="hidden response">
                                Vielen Dank für Ihr Feedback!
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="sa-button-container">
                        <button tabindex="2" class="cancel" style="display: none; box-shadow: none;">Cancel</button>
                        <div class="sa-confirm-button-container">
                            <button id="commentOK" tabindex="1" class="confirm" style="display: inline-block; box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px rgba(140,212,245,0.8), inset 0px 0px 0px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.05);">OK</button>
                            <div class="la-ball-fall">
                                <div></div>
                                <div></div>
                                <div></div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
</form>
```

The first box works ok. The second box however, for some reason  doesn't close after clicking on the OK button. My .css looks like this:

```
/* The Modal (background) */
.modal {
  display: none; /* Hidden by default */
  position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
  z-index: 999; /* Sit on top */
  padding-top: 100px; /* Location of the box */
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%; /* Full width */
  height: 100%; /* Full height */
  overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */
  background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4); /* Black w/ opacity */
}

/* Modal Content */
.modal-content {
  background-color: #fefefe;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #888;
  width: 80%;
}

/* The Close Button */
.close {
  color: #aaaaaa;
  float: right;
  font-size: 28px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}


.modalheader{

    margin: -17px -17px 15px;
    padding: 10px 15px;
    background-color: #f2fcde;
    border-bottom: 1px solid silver;
    font-weight: 600;
    line-height: 40px;
    display: -ms-flexbox !important;
    font-family: inherit;
    font-size: 7;
}
```

Here my js:

```
function myFunction(modalElem){
// Get the modal
var modal = document.getElementById(modalElem);

// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span = document.getElementById("commentOK");

  modal.style.display = "block";


// When the user clicks on <span> (OK), close the modal
span.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "none";
}
```

I tried placing the code for modal windows outside the "form" close to the body at the bottom in the html file but that didnt help. I'm not an experienced html programmer and whatever the bug is, I just couldn't find it. How can I fix this?

Comment: You have two elements using ```id="commentOk"``` and they are both buttons. Would it not be easier to add an ```onClick ``` function to each of these instead?

Comment: I didn't think about that. There will be many more question mark icons with modal windows. I thought it's more practical like this with a single onclick function for all

Comment: It would be easy to understand if you can provide [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem comes as you are using same id for both buttons in both modals. `document.getElementById` search for a unique element with that id in the whole document, and in result it just returns first element in HTML with that id.

It is recommended to use unique id in HTML elements

> If the id value is not the empty string, it must be unique in a
>   document.

Check this https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/id

But if you want to stay with repeating ids, you should look for that element from the children in the modal div element. You can use the querySelector to do that and query for id attribute

**Query selector** https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector

**Attribute selectors** https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors

Working example here:

```js
function myFunction(ok) {
  // Get the modal
  var modal = document.getElementById(ok);

  // Get the <span> element that closes the modal
  var span = modal.querySelector("[id=commentOK]");

  modal.style.display = "block";


  // When the user clicks on <span> (OK), close the modal
  span.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

```css
/* The Modal (background) */

.modal {
  display: none;
  /* Hidden by default */
  position: fixed;
  /* Stay in place */
  z-index: 999;
  /* Sit on top */
  padding-top: 100px;
  /* Location of the box */
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  /* Full width */
  height: 100%;
  /* Full height */
  overflow: auto;
  /* Enable scroll if needed */
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  /* Fallback color */
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  /* Black w/ opacity */
}


/* Modal Content */

.modal-content {
  background-color: #fefefe;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #888;
  width: 80%;
}


/* The Close Button */

.close {
  color: #aaaaaa;
  float: right;
  font-size: 28px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.modalheader {
  margin: -17px -17px 15px;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  background-color: #f2fcde;
  border-bottom: 1px solid silver;
  font-weight: 600;
  line-height: 40px;
  display: -ms-flexbox !important;
  font-family: inherit;
  font-size: 7;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-md-4 col-lg-3 required" for="offer_title" id="ThemaLbl">
                <div class="inline-help form-label" data-help="&lt;b&gt;Sie wollen ein
" data-heading="Wie kann ich ein Thema eintragen?" data-help-key="offers.title"><i onClick="myFunction('themaModal')" class="fa fa-question-circle-o" id="ThemaHilfe">?</i></div>Thema</label>
    <div class="col-md-8 col-lg-9">
      <textarea class="longInput" cols="42" rows="1" id="ThemaTextfield"></textarea>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- The Modal -->
  <div id="themaModal" class="modal">

    <!-- Modal content -->
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modalheader">
        <h2
          <b id="hilfeTitel">Wie kann ich eine neue Anzeige erstellen?</b>
        </h2>
      </div>
      <div>
        <p style="display: block;">
          <font size="2" id="hilfeText"><b id="hilfeText">Sie wollen eine neue Anzeige anlegen?</b> Dann tragen Sie die zugehörigen Informationen ein und speichern das Ergebnis am Ende ab.</font>
        </p>
      </div>
      <div>
        <div class="panel panel-default" id="feedback-form">
          <div class="panel-heading">
            <h4 class="panel-title" id="hilfeQuestion">
              <i class="fa fa-question-circle"></i> Waren die Informationen für Sie hilfreich? </h4>
          </div>
          <div class="panel-body">
            <form class="feedback" id="new_feedback" role="form" action="/feedbacks" method="post" accept-charset="UTF-8" data-remote="true">
              <input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="✓">
              <div class="form-group">
                <textarea name="feedback[comment]" class="form-control" id="feedback_comment" placeholder="Sie können uns hier Ihre Anmerkungen mitteilen."></textarea>
              </div>
              <input name="feedback[context]" id="feedback_context" type="hidden" value="/offers/new">
              <input name="feedback[help_key]" id="feedback_help_key" type="hidden" value="help.offers.new">
            </form>
            <div class="hidden response">
              Vielen Dank für Ihr Feedback!
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="sa-button-container">
          <button tabindex="2" class="cancel" style="display: none; box-shadow: none;">Cancel</button>
          <div class="sa-confirm-button-container">
            <button id="commentOK" tabindex="1" class="confirm" style="display: inline-block; box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px rgba(140,212,245,0.8), inset 0px 0px 0px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.05);">OK</button>
            <div class="la-ball-fall">
              <div></div>
              <div></div>
              <div></div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-md-4 col-lg-3" for="offer_content" id="InhaltLbl">
                <div class="inline-help form-label" data-help="&lt;b&gt;Sie
  &lt;/div&gt;
" data-heading="Wie kann ich den Inhalt einer Anzeigen eingeben bzw. bearbeiten?" data-help-key="offers.content"><i onClick="myFunction('inhaltModal')" class="fa fa-question-circle-o" id="InhaltHilfe">?</i></div>Inhalt</label>
    <div class="col-md-8 col-lg-9">
      <textarea class="longInput" cols="42" rows="4" id="InhaltTextfield"></textarea>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- The Modal -->
  <div id="inhaltModal" class="modal">

    <!-- Modal content -->
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modalheader">
        <h2>
          <b id="hilfeTitel">Wie kann ich eine neue Anzeige erstellen?</b>
        </h2>
      </div>
      <div>
        <p style="display: block;">
          <font size="2" id="hilfeText"><b id="hilfeText">Sie wollen eine neue Anzeige anlegen?</b> Dann tragen Sie die zugehörigen Informationen ein und speichern das Ergebnis am Ende ab.</font>
        </p>
      </div>
      <div>
        <div class="panel panel-default" id="feedback-form">
          <div class="panel-heading">
            <h4 class="panel-title" id="hilfeQuestion">
              <i class="fa fa-question-circle"></i> Waren die Informationen für Sie hilfreich? </h4>
          </div>
          <div class="panel-body">
            <form class="feedback" id="new_feedback" role="form" action="/feedbacks" method="post" accept-charset="UTF-8" data-remote="true">
              <input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="✓">
              <div class="form-group">
                <textarea name="feedback[comment]" class="form-control" id="feedback_comment" placeholder="Sie können uns hier Ihre Anmerkungen mitteilen."></textarea>
              </div>
              <input name="feedback[context]" id="feedback_context" type="hidden" value="/offers/new">
              <input name="feedback[help_key]" id="feedback_help_key" type="hidden" value="help.offers.new">
            </form>
            <div class="hidden response">
              Vielen Dank für Ihr Feedback!
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="sa-button-container">
          <button tabindex="2" class="cancel" style="display: none; box-shadow: none;">Cancel</button>
          <div class="sa-confirm-button-container">
            <button id="commentOK" tabindex="1" class="confirm" style="display: inline-block; box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px rgba(140,212,245,0.8), inset 0px 0px 0px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.05);">OK</button>
            <div class="la-ball-fall">
              <div></div>
              <div></div>
              <div></div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks for the tips! I will check them out. In your example l can't see a button that closes the window btw. Also l gave these buttons individual IDs now after your suggestion. but still the same...

Comment: I don't have the icon font loaded, maybe you're showing it with that. I've manipulated slightly the HTML you provided to a smaller font-size and added the quotation mark to show something in order to click it.

Comment: actually you were right about the individual IDs for the element. I needed to put the IDs of the individual buttons for each modal window as parameter with the onclick function call on my HTML. so silly... THANKS!

Answer (score 1):

```
var modal = document.getElementById(ok);
```

I think the problem is the ok inside getElementById must be a string, Try:

```
var modal = document.getElementById('ok');
```

Comment: that doesn't solve the problem. the naming choice for that parameter was a bit unlucky. changed it to "modalElem". that method calls the modal code in the html.